# AWS ECS: How to retrieve tag of currently deployed image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

I currently use the following makeshift script to get the tag of the image that is running in any given environment within ECS:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh                                                                                                                                   
set -euo pipefail                                                                                                                                    
if [[ -z ${1-} ]]                                                                                                                                    
...
    a bunch of prompting and output that's not germane to the question
...                                                                                                                                        
else                                                                                                                                                 
   aws ecs describe-services --services "$2" --cluster "$cluster" \                                                                                  
           | jq ".services[0].deployments[0].taskDefinition" \                                                                                       
           | xargs -I {} aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition {} \                                                                     
           | jq '.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].image' \                                                                                    
           | awk '{gsub(/"/,"",$0); split($0,a,":"); print a[2]}'                                                                          
fi
```

That gets me the commit hash that's appended onto the image URI. For example, if the image URI is `476012345675.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myorg-github:9942baf189f0eff596db0fbf06bfc6dcf42d5709`, this script prints `9942baf189f0eff596db0fbf06bfc6dcf42d5709`

Is there a better way to do this, aside from re-writing it in Python and using `boto3` API calls?

Comment: I don't think there's a better way. The only foolproof place to look for that is in the currently active task definition. That script doesn't look that brittle, does it actually fail a lot?

Comment: @MarkB perhaps "incredibly brittle" was a bit overboard. I've edited the wording to moderate the tone. It has broken on me--after switching the service to CodeDeploy. My question would be: why isn't there an API call that simply returns the active task definition? After all, I'm supplying the service and the cluster name.

Comment: "My question would be: why isn't there an API call that simply returns the active task definition?" The ECS APIs are definitely lacking some basic "describe-*" methods that would make this sort of thing a lot easier. As for **why** they are lacking, I doubt anyone from AWS is going to drop by and give an answer to that.